# MongoDB ODataController Get method

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, odata, mongodb-.net-driver

How do you pass an ObjectId into an ODataController GET method?

Since the ObjectId is the unique identifier of a document, my first thought was to do something like this, where '542978c4e4b0e67da1edc7f3' is the ObjectId:

```
odata/Teams(542978c4e4b0e67da1edc7f3)
```

But when I do this, my GET method does not pick this up, the ObjectId is empty {000000000000000000000000} :

```
public Team GetTeam(ObjectId id)
        {
            var teams = mongoDatabase.GetCollection("Teams");
            var team = teams.FindOneById(id);
....
```

I am only just starting out with MongoDB, what is the correct way to do this, or am I using the wrong approach completely?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the tutorial http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataServiceSample/ODataService here. Seems you are missing [FromODataUri] for the input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult GetTeam([FromODataUri] string id)
{
    var teams = mongoDatabase.GetCollection("Teams");

    // convert the string 'id' to BsonValue 'bsonId'
    ......

    var team = teams.FindOneById(bsonId);

    // convert 'team' to the entity type Team object 'team'
    ......

    return Ok(team);
}
```

Then query the entity set by:

```
GET odata/Teams('542978c4e4b0e67da1edc7f3')
```

as OData URL supports string as parameter.

Comment: What would be the correct syntax to convert the string 'id' to BsonValue 'bsonId'?

Comment: @user517406 Just "BsonValue bsonValue = id;"

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId is a class. Use attribute **"key"** and annotation **[FromODataUri]**.

```
public Team GetTeam([FromODataUri] string key)
{
    var teams = mongoDatabase.GetCollection("Teams");
    var team = teams.FindOneById(ObjectId.Parse(key));
    ...
}
```